# WordPress: Delete all Posts from user after one post has been deleted

Tags: php, wordpress, api, custom-post-type

I'm using serveral Custom Post Types in WordPress.
Every user can add a company profile as a specific post type called "company".
If the user has a company profile he can add more content like jobs, events and more. All defined as specific Custom Post Types.

It is also possible that the user deletes his own company profile.
If he do so, all other posts from the user should be deleted as well (except normal posts) and the URL should be redirected (301) to the homepage.

I've found the action "delete_post" in the WP docs (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post). But I'm not sure how to fire it.

Does anyone has an hint?

**EDIT:** See my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was the action 'delete_post'.
I've changed it to 'trash_to_publish' based on the Post Status Transitions: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions

Now everything works fine.

```
/**
 * Deletes all posts from author of company profile.
 */
function delete_all_posts_from_author($post_id) {


    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;

    // Only trigger if post type is "company"
    if ( get_post_type($id) == "company" ) {

        $author_id = $post->post_author;

        $posts_from_author = get_posts(
            array(
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'post_status'       => 'publish',
                'post_type'         => array('event','job'),
                'author'            => $author_id,
                'fields'            => 'ids', // Only get post ID's
            )
        );

        foreach ( $posts_from_author as $post_from_author ) {
            wp_trash_post( $post_from_author, false); // Set to False if you want to send them to Trash.
        }
    }


}

add_action( 'publish_to_trash',  'delete_all_posts_from_author', 10, 1 );
```

As a bonus I could use the function to **publish all posts from a user again if I untrash** the company profile.

```
/**
 * Untrash posts if company profile is untrashed
 */
function untrash_all_posts_from_author($post_id) {


    global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;

    if ( get_post_type($id) == "company" ) {

        $author_id = $post->post_author;

        $posts_from_author = get_posts(
            array(
                'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                'post_status'       => 'trash',
                'post_type'         => array('event','job'),
                'author'            => $author_id,
                'fields'            => 'ids', // Only get post ID's
            )
        );

        foreach ( $posts_from_author as $post_from_author ) {
            wp_untrash_post( $post_from_author); // Set to False if you want to send them to Trash.
        }
    }


}

add_action( 'trash_to_publish',  'untrash_all_posts_from_author', 10, 1 );
```

Hope that helps. And please let me know if I've made a mistake.

**EDIT:** I've changed the argument `wp_delete_post()` to `wp_trash_post()` because `wp_delete_post()` only applies to native posts, pages, and attachments. Great answer from @rarst here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/281877/error-after-deleting-custom-post-type-with-a-function-no-trash-used/281888#281888

Comment: Looks good :) The only thing is wp_untrash_post() takes one parameter only, but this is solid.

Comment: Same as what @DanielH.J. said - but for `wp_trash_post()`, @Cray. It only takes 1 parameter, the post_id. I think you're confusing with `wp_delete_post()` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
// Add action trigger
add_action( 'delete_post', 'delete_other_custom_posts', 10 );

function delete_other_custom_posts( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $post = get_post( $post_id );

    // Only trigger if post type is "company"
    if ( $post->post_type == "company" ) {
        $author_id = $post->post_author;

        // Find other custom posts' ids by the same user
        $posts_to_delete = $wpdb->get_col(
            $wpdb->prepare(
                "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_author = %d AND post_type IN (<put your custom post types' slugs here>)",
                $author_id
            ), ARRAY_A
        );

        if ( $posts_to_delete ) {
            foreach ( $posts_to_delete as $post_delete_id ) {
                // Delete the custom post
                wp_delete_post( $post_delete_id );
            }
        }

        // Redirect
        wp_redirect(<page you want to redirect to>);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I've added the post-type slugs like this: "post_type IN ('event','job')" but unfortunately it doesn' work?!

Comment: Maybe it's because the function wp_delete post does not wor for custom post types? The WP docs says "Removes or trashes a post, attachment, or page."

Comment: Custom post types are also posts, just with a different name. Do you see any errors in PHP's error log? Try var_dump( $posts_to_delete ) and see what is returned.

Comment: Hi Daniel, you can see my answer below. I think it was to action "delete_post"

Answer (score 1):

It's possible.
company is post type so remaining content will be taxonomy so when you delete post there meta,taxonomy will not be delete.

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_init', 'codex_init' );
function codex_init() {
    add_action( 'delete_post', 'codex_sync', 10 );
}

function codex_sync( $pid ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT post_id FROM .'$wpdb->prefix.'postmeta WHERE post_id = %d', $pid ) ) ) {
        $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 'DELETE FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'postmeta WHERE post_id = %d', $pid ) );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, but the remaining content is also a post type not a taxonomy